# How to get datatable column value on xPage?

Tags: java, jdbc, xpages

I have a datatable on my xPage that uses page datasource (jdbcQuery). By clicking on some form button I want to read one entire column into scopevariable either from datatable or datasource itself. How to do that? Thanks.

OK, let's say I have a combobox on my page. And it should have unique values one of datatable column. Datatable updates - then combobox updates with column values

Comment: Does the datatable and the button have to be dependent on each other?  Is there a reason why the two queries need to be connected?

Comment: they should not really depend on each other. but does it really matter? I want just by click on a button or any other component, e.g, bring a message box that shows content of entire column, e.g. separated by comma. Ok this data table filters data output.. so I want to use current column values shown in some other place. I'm trying to play with  getComponent("dataTable1").getChildren().get(..)

Comment: I am having a little trouble following what you desire to accomplish, but one approach would consider building an independent query to show your column values.  Build your SQL query based on the datatable filters and any other dependencies.

Comment: sure I can use another query for my combobox. But I want to use data that already returned in datatable from datasource. If I have 100 controls on my page that I need to updated based on datatable state - then would I need to issue 100 sql queries? I don't wanna do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I get from both your topic description and your discussion with Steve I assume that you are building a datasource using jdbc and passing that into a datatable control. In addition you want to be able to access what finally is displayed in one of the datatable columns using some other control like a comboBox - did I get this right?

In that case I would use some kind of temporary datastore (e.g. inside a javabean object or a scoped variable) to store your collected and probably filtered SQL data. Then both your datatable and any other set of controls would get their data from that data store; this should be way more effective than what I think you tried to accomplish.

*Edit:*

assuming that your SQL querying code is written in Java you can import `javax.faces.context.FacesContext` and `javax.faces.context.ExternalContext`. Then instantiate your objects like this

```
private FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
private ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
```

From here you can access all 4 scopes as objects of `java.util.Map` (as you can see `viewScope` is a bit different from the others):

```
private Map applicationScope = externalContext.getApplicationMap();
private Map sessionScope = externalContext.getSessionMap();
private Map requestScope = externalContext.getRequestMap();
private Map viewScope = facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewMap();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Lothar. Yes you understood my question right. So my datatable is connected to datasource. But how do I put datasource output into a scopevariable? At what point and where?

Comment: sorry for a late answer; couldn't find time to check stackoverflow recently... - I added some example code to my answer